# What are the names of the each number system?

Tags: soft-question, number-systems

I am not a native english speaker and i was wondering what the names for each number system is. I was looking on the internet but only found the common ones like binary, trinary or doudecimal. Can anyone help me out here? I am especially looking for the names of the 7-er system or the 9-er system up to the hexadecimal system.

Comment: 2:binary, 3:[ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system), 4:quaternary, 5:quinary, 6:senary, 7:septenary, 8:octal, 9:nonary, 10:decimal, 12:duodecimal, 16:hexadecimal... (ref: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system))

Comment: However, except for decimal, binary, octal, and hexadecimal, these names are almost never used, and if used, would have to be explained to most people. Usually, people just say "base-3". Octal and hexadecimal are used mostly in computer science, and most people not conversant in that subject will not recognize them either. Only decimal and binary are widely known.